# How to post on facebook groups with selenium? Python

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, post

I'm trying to post on facebook groups with selenium.
I can log on as me, but I cant identify the tags of text fields...

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 #Login
 brow = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python34\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
 brow.get("http://www.facebook.com")

 login = brow.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='email']")
 login.send_keys("email")

 senha = brow.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pass']")
 senha.send_keys("pass")

 entrar = brow.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='u_0_l']")
 entrar.click()
 print("LOGGED")

 brow.get("GROUP LINK")
 caixaTxt = brow.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-offset-key='//*[@id='js_1u']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/span']") #This tag doesnt work
 caixaTxt.send_keys("Good Afternoon!")
 postar = brow.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Publicar')]")
 postar.click()
 print("POSTED")
```

Please help me!!

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed. Use the API.

Comment: @WizKid but I want to post with my account, and not with the application

Comment: You can as long as you are admin of the group. If you are not admin of the group there is no way to do it

Comment: @WizKid OK, Thanks